# how to resize image height and width

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am using ionic2.

I display the list of images.But these have different height and width.

Here is my URL

https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/apartments-ea9e5.appspot.com/o/bulletinboard%2Fsample-1494575890205.jpg?alt=media&token=69debcf1-c563-4799-8768-e64a58103e56

another URL

https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/apartments-ea9e5.appspot.com/o/bulletinboard%2Fsample-1494575890149.jpg?alt=media&token=81122cfa-290a-400e-b6e8-925f13db5291

I need these images are same height and width using javascript.

How can i do this?

Kindly advice me,

Thanks.

Comment: I think this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36698925/resize-image-in-ionic-cards) will help you

Comment: Thanks for ur reply.http://codepen.io/jannahody/pen/jqxRxp?editors=1100 .i see the demo.These images are same height and width.But i have different sizes of images..I have no idea..